# How to have left-justified text and right-justified text on the same line?

Tags: macros, spacing, pdftex, positioning, alignment

I want to have `Progress Report` on the leftmost and the date on the rightmost section of a single line.

So I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\raggedleft{Progress Report} 
\raggedright{19. Jan 2023}

\end{document}
```

While `Progress Report` is pushed to the left as expected, the date is not pushed to the right and is also pushed to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\raggedleft{Progress Report} \\
\raggedright{19. Jan 2023}

\end{document}
```

What is even more weird is that when I add a newline between the two commands, `Progress Report` is now pushed to the right and the date is pushed to the left on the next line.

How should I revise my code to achieve intended behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to LaTeX!

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

%\raggedleft{Progress Report} 
%\raggedright{19. Jan 2023}
\noindent%may be needed in some situations
Progress Report
\hfill
19. Jan 2023

\end{document}
```

> What is even more weird is that when I add a newline between the two commands, Progress Report is now pushed to the right and the date is pushed to the left on the next line.

The choice of text alignment applies to the entire paragraph. You cannot use both `raggedright` and `raggedleft` in the same paragraph.